# Is it possible to create a line with occasional discontinuities or a line comprising multiple independent strips in three.js?

Tags: three.js, line, drawing

I have a function that generates a series of points to define a line, but the function occasionally needs to "lift the pen" and then continue drawing from a new location. I would like to minimize the coding overhead associated with lifting the pen. I would also like to avoid the performance penalty of doubling up the number of points and using "LineSegments".

Is there any way to specify that I want the pen be lifted between specific pairs of points in the strip? Is there any other simple solution to this problem?

This is the code that I have now...

```
const tetherPoints = myDrawingFunction()
const tetherGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(tetherPoints)
var tetherMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
  color: 0x4897f8,                      // Note: This attribute does not seem to have any effect
  transparent: true,
  opacity: dParam.tetherVisibility
})
const tempTether = new THREE.Line(tetherGeometry, tetherMaterial)
scene.add(tempTether)
```

Comment: `LineSegments` with an indexed buffer geometry: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/using-nan-in-attributes/1952/7

Comment: For reference, the link above is to sample code that uses recursive calls to draw snowflakes. I think the technique uses by this code is: 1) To create a geometry by creating an array of vertices (positions), and 2) A second array of indices which select individual vertices, where there are two indices per line segment, and then 3) Use THREE.LineSegments.

Comment: Phil is correct. This idea is your vertex array only has one copy of each vertex (`[ x0, y0, z0, x1, ... zN ]`) and then the index buffer references it like: `[ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]` which indicates a segment between vertices `0` and `1`, `1` and `2`, then a break between `2` and `3`, followed by another segment between `3` and `4`, and so on.

Comment: I played around with code to create pairs of indices that correctly point to vertices, and came away feeling that my code became more complex and harder to understand. Also, the memory gain of having fewer points is partially clawed back by the need for two additional indices per point. So, I'm wondering if other approaches might exist. Is it possible, for example, to define a geometry comprising an array of strips (and no indices)? Or, is there a more efficient indexing mechanism that uses a list of (start, length) pairs?